# JSON parse data with RETROFIT2

Tags: java, android, json, list, retrofit

I got this problem when try to get json data. if you need full source to find problem or mistake i can upload it.

Here is image of problem.
[PROBLEM HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT1FN.png)

Main Activity.java

```html
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button bOpenPref;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Product> listing;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Kreiranje i dovlacenje Preferences screen-a

        //Ovo je zakomentirano jer više nema svrhu , prebačeno u ActionBar Vidi onOptionsItemSelected klasu
//        bOpenPref = findViewById(R.id.bOpenPreferences);
//
//        bOpenPref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesScreenActivity.class);
//                startActivity(intent);
//            }
//        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
//        ImageLoaderConfiguration config=new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
//        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        listing = new ArrayList<>();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("REMOVED")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APiService service = retrofit.create(APiService.class);
        Call<List<Product>> call=   service.getbookdetails();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Product>> call, Response<List<Product>> response) {

                List<Product> list = response.body();
                Product product = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    product = new Product();
                    String name = list.get(i).getName();
                    String color = list.get(i).getRank();
                  //  String image = list.get(i).getImageurl();
                    String price = list.get(i).getPriceUsd();
                    product.setPriceUsd(price);
                    product.setRank(color);
                    product.setName(name);
                  //  product.setImageurl(image);
                    listing.add(product);
                }


                Recycleradapter recyclerAdapter = new Recycleradapter(listing);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);
                // RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingdecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

            }



    //Ovo nam pomaže kako nebi morali gasiti aplikaciju da se Settings prikaže
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreference();
    }
//Ovo nije radilo- pa sam ponovno napravio
//    @Override
//    protected void onReume() {
//        super.onResume();
//        getPreference();
//    }


    //Ovo je klasa koju smo sami gore kreirali kako bi mogli odrediti boje od pozadine kroz Settings
    //Tu još možeš i mjenjati text boju od texViewa sa metodom ||myTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);||
    //Ili ovako ||ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);||
    private void getPreference() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (preferences.contains("color")) {
            if (preferences.getString("color", "0").equals("1")) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else if (preferences.getString("color", "0").equals("2")) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    }


    //OLD ACTION BAR EDIT
//        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
////        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_24dp);
//        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
//        actionBar.setTitle(“ActivityName”);


//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_24dp);
//        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
//        actionBar.setTitle(“Edit Conference”);





            //Ovdje govorimo na koji main menu mislimo
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Ovdje govorimo sto ce tocno klik na settings u action baru otvoriti
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.your_item_id) {
            //A ovo je metoda za pozivanje i startanje preferences activity-a
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class GridSpacingdecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int span;
        private int space;
        private boolean include;

        public GridSpacingdecoration(int span, int space, boolean include) {
            this.span = span;
            this.space = space;
            this.include = include;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            int column = position % span;

            if (include) {
                outRect.left = space - column * space / span;
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * space / span;

                if (position < span) {
                    outRect.top = space;
                }
                outRect.bottom = space;
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * space / span;
                outRect.right = space - (column + 1) * space / span;
                if (position >= span) {
                    outRect.top = space;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }
}
```

APIService.java

```html
package REMOVED
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

/**
 * Created by csa on 01-May-17.
 */

public interface APiService {

    @GET("ticker/")
    Call<List<Book>> getbookdetails();

}
```

And that is it he says problem is in ApiService.java and MainActivity.java
Thank you on your time i hope someone will look and find my problem , i lost a lot of hours probably days and still i can not get it :(

Comment: You should upload the relevant part of the code, so that people can help you. Take care to minimise the code as much as possible, removing sections before or after which are not relevant.

Comment: ApiService <> APiService. And Book is not defined most probably due to a missing import.

Comment: Your class is named `APiService` and the file is named `ApiService`. Correct one of them

Comment: Juan i don't get you what i need to change ? just name of file or ?

Comment: C:\Users\Domo\Desktop\REMOVED\app\src\main\java\com\example\domo\cryptotrace\ApiService.java:11: error: class APiService is public, should be declared in a file named APiService.java
public interface APiService {
       ^
C:\Users\Domo\Desktop\REMOVED\app\src\main\java\com\example\domo\cryptotrace\ApiService.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    Call<List<Book>> getbookdetails();
              ^
  symbol:   class Book
  location: interface APiService
2 errors


That is from Gradle Console, i still didn't got where is the problem ? 

Seems like i am stupid for this :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found answer alone.

I was removed from ApiService.java public
and removed ApiService to aPiService.

Also Call> needed to be removed to >

Thank you for your time guys.